# How to train 3D point cloud data? Where should I beginn?

Tags: 3d, deep-learning, point-cloud-library, lidar-data

I'm an automotive engineer student, and at the moment I'm working in a project for an autonomous bus at the university with 3D point clouds from a lidar sensor. My job here is to train the point cloud with deep learning algorithms. But I do not know exactly how to start. I found many sources on the internet. But it is also too diverse for me as a beginner, I do not know how to start first. Can someone give me some tips? Or good source for beginners.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: AFAIK, deep learning on point clouds is not settled yet on a 'canonical' way to go (Sparse convolutions vs PointNet-derived vs other less common for now). You can search for most recent lectures or presentations with overview of this topic and then follow links. Look for example https://www.qwertee.io/blog/deep-learning-with-point-clouds/.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, I assume that you are working on your own LiDAR point cloud data rather than the public datasets.
Initially, I would suggest annotating the data with 3D bounding boxes on point cloud data.

As concerned about deep learning algorithms I would prefer understanding [Complex YOLO](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.06199), [VoxelNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.06396), and PointNet.
To understand the implementation PointNet algorithm you can refer to the [Keras webpage](https://keras.io/examples/vision/pointnet/) trained on the ModelNet10 dataset.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches:

- ***Feature engineering*** (user-defined global and/or [local features](https://doi.org/10.5194/isprsannals-II-3-181-2014))
- ***Feature learning*** (models such as [PointNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00593), [PointNet++](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02413), and [VoxNet](https://doi.org/10.1109/IROS.2015.7353481))

If the feature engineering approach is selected, you can train your model with several different classifiers, such as Multilayer Perceptron (MLP), Support Vector Machines (SVM), and Random Forest (RF), for instance.